# Serializing an object containing an array and an int

Tags: java, serialization

I have been trying to implement a way to save some of my Objects in a file so that I can cut down on the need for filling a variable each run time which can take upwards of 20 minutes. I am currently in the midst of using an Object called a Raster which can be filled using a type File which is used to pull data into the fields. I am wondering how I would be able to serialize the following.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Raster implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 15L;
    private int col,row,NODATA;
    private double [] [] Ras;
    public Raster (File inData) throws IOException
    {
    //open file as f
    BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inData));
    this.col = Integer.parseInt(f.readLine().substring(5).trim());
    this.row = Integer.parseInt(f.readLine().substring(5).trim());
    f.readLine();
    f.readLine();
    f.readLine();
    this.NODATA = Integer.parseInt(f.readLine().substring(12).trim());
    //now the data will be added
    this.Ras = new double [row] [col];
    for (int r = 0 ; r <row;r ++ )
        {
        String[] vals = f.readLine().split(" ");
        for (int c = 0 ; c < col; c ++ )
            this.Ras[r][c]= Double.parseDouble(vals[c]);
        }
    f.close();
    }
    public int getRows() {
        return row;
    }
    public int getCols() {
        return col;
    }
    public double getData(int rowPos, int colPos) {
        return Ras[rowPos][colPos];
    }
}
```

I have looked at some other examples but they all seem to be rather specific to other types of data other than an array inside of an object and so I hope that someone might be able to explain a way I might be able to serialize this.

P.S.
I have edited the code to better Explain my problem as it sems it isn't clear enough. When using the serialize this class it would come up with an error like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

when I ran my code which looks like this

```
if (rasPath.exists()) {
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(rasPath));
                Raster SqrRas =  (Raster) (in).readObject();
                in.close();         
            }
            else {
                Raster SqrRas = new Raster (fullPath);
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(rasPath));
                out.writeObject(SqrRas);
                out.close();
            }
```

Comment: Implement `Serializeable` Interface & save it to file [refer](http://www.studytonight.com/java/serialization-and-deserialization.php)

Comment: @ClementAmarnath Sorry i didn't clarify this but this file is utilized to store large sums of data from a different class and through some of my testing in that other file i was unable to Serialize the object from that class due to errors which i will now add to my post.

Comment: information is updated with a sample example of my issues with the recieving of data. In case it is necesary the variables are all declared as so:      rasPath is a file folder path which is where the data will be placed in the file.    FullPath is the place where the data is held for the object.

Comment: @AndrewLinington - I could only see `out.flush();` missing before `out.close();` , try by adding flush to your code

Comment: @ClementAmarnath got it to work by changing the way my path name was declared but what does out.flush(); do?

Comment: @ClementAmarnath: *"...explain why you need serialization here, since there is no ... data transfer over the network?"*  There are other valid uses for serialization.  Implementations of the Enterprise Java Bean specification 3.1+, for example, may use serialization/deserialization as the mechanism for passivation & re-activation of stateful beans from/to application server memory.

Comment: @ClementAmarnath It is for you to explain why you think that serialization should only be used over a network. Your comment is incomprehensible.

Comment: @scottb but in regards to the use of what i am doing I A) am not using java bean but instead eclipse and B) am only using serialization to store data to be called on that specific computer it is used on. I thank you for some of the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to deserialize from an empty file.

Comment: In a sense yes I was as the file itself was created with a path akin to that of /**/**/**/Ras.txt.ser. It should have been /**/**/**/Ras.ser so as a result the data file was empty.

Comment: I do not understand. If you created it with a different path, it was *missing*, not empty. Do you have a pointless `File.createNewFile()` somewhere? Remove it. NB Serialized data is not text and should not be saved in files with the .txt extension.

Answer (score -1):

in regards to my issue i found out it was actually due to my path name having an extension created inaccurately thus preventing the data from being located. All is good

Comment: That would cause a `FileNotFoundExveption`, not an empty file. You must have created the file with the correct name as an empty file somewhere. Are you using `File.createNewFile()` before trying to open it? If so, don't

Comment: upon closing java the file appeared thus i must reload to see it sorry about that. @EJP

Comment: I can only repeat If you saved it to a wrong name you would have got a `FileNotFoundException` when you tried to open it with the right name, and if you tried to open it with the name you saved it with, it would have worked. None of this explains an `EOFExecption`, which in this case is caused by an empty file, as it happened when reading the stream header.